# Conflicting Gitlab CI Rules Statements

Tags: gitlab-ci, rules

We have a Gitlab pipeline that is failing to lint because two imported templates contain conflicting rules statements.  An older template contains `when: manual` and `only: web` and another template uses `rules: if $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"`.  Since the `rules: if` style statement appears to be more up to date can we update the older template to use `rules: if $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"` in direct replacement of the `when: manual` and `only: web` statements and achieve the same result?

Comment: To be clear: you're importing two different templates that implement a job of the same name? Maybe that situation is best to be avoided to begin with. One problem you may run into updating the old template is if other users of the template add their own `only:`/`except:` keys, which are incompatible with `rules:`, they will be broken by such an update. But otherwise, yes, you can achieve the same effect using `rules:`.